# NetSuite SCA Online Edit

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

Hello NetSuite SCA developers,

I am given access to SCA site where I can edit HTML on some part of the page. I am not sure what this feature is, but to show the online editor, you just press Esc key. I am thinking that the "editable" part is defined through the main template which I don't have access to. I have experience with Site Builder but not SCA, so my questions are:

**1. What is this feature called?** I need the appropriate term when I talk to client.

**2. How do I edit other sections (like header, footer) or possibly the full HTML of a page? Can an admin give me permission or would it take a technical person to edit the main template?**

My goal is that I need to edit the menus and header but I could not. I will request it to the client but I don't know what to request since I don't have much idea how it is set up and how it works. If someone could enlighten me just the basics, that would be awesome!

P.S. SuiteCloud IDE would not be an option. We don't have access to full source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature name is 'Site Management Tool' SMT give you access & edit site when you press ctrl+esc key. But Remember it has so many limitation. I won't recommend it to use every where, Specially for menu structure.

With SMT allow you to add CMS areas, CMS area are Text area, Image Area, Merchandizing area and HTML area.

You will have some default CMS area on each pages,

```
<div class="home-cms-page-banner-bottom" data-cms-area="home_banner_1" data-cms-area-filters="path"></div>
```

Then only you can add above 4 area with 'Site Management Tool'.

You can not edit the Menu & header if it don't have CMS area added within code.  To edit menu you need to check if it site has category or facets? if it has category based menu then you can edit it from back end.

Let me know if this explanation is good?